# Using Twitter's 1.1 API and RFC 1738 URL Encoding Requirement

Tags: encodingutil

I need to upgrade some code I have that uses Twitter's API to updates follower counts for their contacts, and the new API requires authentication. In reading [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) piece about it, I apparently need to encode my URL using the [RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) Format (though at this stage that doesn't seem to actually change anything?)

Does the Apex encodingUTIL support that format? It doesn't seem to with some basic tests e.g

```
String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('123456', 'RFC 1738')
```

throws an eror that RFC 1738 is not supported, but that could be a syntax issue...

Or if not, can I use some other format to achieve the same outcome? Or has anyone used Twitter's 1.1 REST API and can shed some light on how to call the API based on the link above?

Comment: you can use [PageReference.parameters](http://www.ratsaas.com/querystring) as an RFC query string builder / parser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RFC 1738 isn't actually a character encoding, which is what the second argument for urlEncode expects. That second argument needs to be something like 'UTF-8' or 'US-ASCII'. Take a look at [the wikipedia article on character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) for more details, but these days this should pretty much always be 'UTF-8' unless you have a very good reason to use something else.

Salesforce doesn't seem to specify what RFC their urlEncode method is based off of, but I'd be thoroughly amazed if it was anything other than RFC 1738, as that's the defacto standard for all URL encoding internet-wide.

With all that said, you really won't see the impact of urlEncode unless you have special characters in your input string, like:

```
EncodingUtil.urlEncode('123456&7', 'UTF-8')
```

returns:

```
'123456%267'
```

having encoded the literal & into it's URL-friendly form of %26.

Long story short: urlEncode should do exactly what you want if you use a UTF-8 encoding.

Edit: User320's suggestion of using a [PageReference to build your URL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=PageReference%7CPageReferences%7CpageReference), and then calling getURL for your automatically-formatted URL is perfectly valid and generally easier to use for most cases.

Comment: That worked...thanks. Once I understood that piece, the move to Twitter 1.1 and authenticated requests was actually pretty straightforward...